# RecyclerView is not showing anything

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

In my application I am getting data from sqlite database and showing them using RecyclerView. 
This is my adapter :-

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.Holder> {

private List<SentData> dataList = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SentData> dataList) {
    Log.d("array size", dataList.size()+"");
    this.dataList = dataList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new Holder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.Holder viewHolder, int position) {
    SentData current = dataList.get(position);

    Log.d("Required data is", current.circleName + current.retailName);
    viewHolder.circleName.setText(current.circleName);
    viewHolder.retailName.setText(current.retailName);
    viewHolder.retailAddress.setText(current.retailAddress);
    viewHolder.captureOn.setText(current.captureDate);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}


class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView retailName, retailAddress, circleName, captureOn;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        retailName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRetailerName);
        retailAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRetailAddress);
        circleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCircleName);
        captureOn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCaptureOn);
    }
}
```

}

SentData is a class

```
public class SentData {
String circleName, retailName, retailAddress, captureDate, syncId, detailId;
}
```

I am not getting any error but the list is not showing. I am trying check with debugger, I found that the onBindViewHolder() method is not running.

In the RecyclerViewAdapter constructor I got the dataList size is 2 that means data is successfully retrieved from sqlite database.

Now I cant find out what is the problem and why its not working please help me.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Collections.emptyList()** returns an empty *immutable* list, you should use **new ArrayList<>()** instead.
Then after you add/remove data from the list must call **notifyDataSetChanged()** for the changes to be seen.
Also **getItemCount()** should return **dataList.size()**

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 0 on `getItemCount()`. Make sure you return the size of 
list that backs the `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem..Your code is completely fine but it is not displaying any list because you are returning **0** in method **getItemCount()**.Just return
**dataList.size()** in your case and it wil work.