# on bind view holder does not run in adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a strange problem. I want to show some products in a `RecyclerView`. I pass a list to the adapter to show. In the constructor of the adapter, the list is set, but no other method is called. While I'm debugging, the list is set, but nothing else happens and nothing will be displayed

This is my code for the adapter:

```
public class SearchItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchItemAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {
    List<Product> products;
    public SearchItemAdapter(){
        products=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new SearchViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void onbind(List<Product> products){
        this.products=products;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder searchViewHolder, int i) {
        Product product= products.get(i);
        Picasso.get().load(product.getPic()).into(searchViewHolder.image);
        searchViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        searchViewHolder.txtDesc.setText(product.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    public class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView txtTitle,txtDesc;
        public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_searchItem_title);
            txtDesc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_searchItem_desc);
            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_searchItem_image);
        }
    }
}
```

and activity codes:

```
public class CompareSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CompareViewModel viewModel=new CompareViewModel();
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable=new CompositeDisposable();
    EditText edtSearch;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView imgClose;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SearchItemAdapter searchItemAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compare_search);
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rv_compareSearch_searchedProduct);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        searchItemAdapter=new SearchItemAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchItemAdapter);
        imgClose=findViewById(R.id.img_compareSearch_close);
        imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        edtSearch=findViewById(R.id.edt_compareSearch_serach);
        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                viewModel.getSearchedProduct(String.valueOf(s))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Product>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                                compositeDisposable.add(d);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<Product> products) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                searchItemAdapter.onbind(products);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                Log.i("LOG", "onError: "+e.toString());
                            }
                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progress_compareSearch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView is not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857213/recyclerview-is-not-showing-anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget RecyclerView to set adapter

> recyclerView.setAdapter(searchItemAdapter);

And change the code as well as like below

```
public void onbind(List<Product> products){
    this.products.clear();
    this.products.addAll(products);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> Set adapter like below

```
private void setupViews() {
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rv_compareSearch_searchedProduct);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        searchItemAdapter=new SearchItemAdapter();

        // Here is the adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchItemAdapter);

        imgClose=findViewById(R.id.img_compareSearch_close);
        imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        edtSearch=findViewById(R.id.edt_compareSearch_serach);
        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                viewModel.getSearchedProduct(String.valueOf(s))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Product>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                                compositeDisposable.add(d);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<Product> products) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                searchItemAdapter.onbind(products);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                Log.i("LOG", "onError: "+e.toString());
                            }
                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progress_compareSearch);
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work yet.I do not know why onbindviewholder is not called

Answer (score 0):

i am not clear about that but, i have one suggestion for you

instead of using `viewgroup.getContext()` , pass activity context in adapter as below,

```
List<Product> products;
Context context;
public SearchItemAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    products=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and use context,

hope your problem solve.